# select hidden input in div, unable to find; however source shows input tag in div

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

this is what the page looks like

```
<div id="DivID">
    <input type="hidden" id="Hidden1" value="Value1" />
    <input type="hidden" id="Hidden2" value="Value2" />

    <bunch of other tags>
</div>
```

When I do `$("#DivID").find("input#Hidden1").val()` I'm getting undefined.
However when I `$(":input#Hidden1").val()` I'm getting Value1

Investigating further, `$("#DivID").html()` simply returns  with the hidden inputs not in sight.

I can confirm that the input tags are inside the div.

**UPDATE**
Input fields were getting moved out of the div and into the head of the page for some reason.

Moving the input fields to the bottom of the div kept them from wandering and allowed me to get the functionality I was looking for.

As far as how or why this was happening, I haven't the foggiest idea.  This issue occured with IE 8.0.6.

If anybody can point me to any sort of bug report for this issue or explain the how and/or why I'll accept their answer.

Comment: And $("#DivID input#Hidden1").val()? And if you're using IDs why not just $("#Hidden1").val()? Doesn't explain what's happening particularly, but alternate solutions are still solutions.

Comment: Check it http://jsfiddle.net/SBmmx/ here It is working fine

Comment: The reason I don't want to use $("#Hidden1") is this is for a control I insert into other pages.  While it would work I like knowing that I'm selecting what I think I'm selecting.  Sort of like setting up some UI scope.

Comment: So strange.  When I plop all of my html into jsfiddle I can get this aspect to work (alert($("#DivID input#Hidden1").val())) yet when I strip down my javascript file in my own document it doesn't function correctly from inside $(document).ready().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `.html()` call returns no inner elements as well, it seems they're either not where you think, or being added later.

- Check that first your markup is valid here: http://validator.w3.org/
- Also make sure they aren't being added dynamically later, *after* your current code is running.

Comment: $("#Hidden1").parent().html() shows that somehow my input fields are getting moved out of the div and into the head of the file.